# type defined with using can't be used as function parameter

Tags: c++, templates, c++17, using

I my real world application I use CRTP to construct a more or less big class "stack". I need to know what the "common base" of these classes is so I define inside one of the classes of the "stack" a `type` with `using`. Later on I wan't to use this defined type as a templated function parameter, but this will not work, I always run into "couldn't deduce template parameter 'VAR_TYPE'" with g++.

Is there a chance to fix that problem, because it is not recommended to define the type manually, because the should be changeable automatically if the structure of my "class stack" will change.

```
template < typename T> struct B { using HERE = B<T>; };
template < typename T> struct C: public B<T> { };

template <typename T>
using COMMON_BASE = typename C<T>::HERE;

template < typename T>
void Print2(  )
{
    std::cout << __PRETTY_FUNCTION__ << std::endl;
}

// g++ reports:
// error: no matching function for call to 'CheckMe(COMMON_BASE<int>*&)'
// note: candidate: 'template<class VAR_TYPE> void CheckMe(COMMON_BASE<VAR_TYPE>*)'
// note:   template argument deduction/substitution failed:
// note:   couldn't deduce template parameter 'VAR_TYPE'

template < typename VAR_TYPE >
void CheckMe( COMMON_BASE<VAR_TYPE>* ) { std::cout << "COMMON_BASE<>" << std::endl; }

// "hardcoded" works fine but should be avoided
//template < typename VAR_TYPE >
//void CheckMe( B<VAR_TYPE>* ) { std::cout << "B<>" << std::endl; }

void CheckMe( int* ) { std::cout << "int" << std::endl; }
//void CheckMe( ... ){ std::cout << "default" << std::endl; }

int main()
{
    COMMON_BASE< int >* cb;
    B<int>* bi;
    CheckMe( cb );
    CheckMe( bi );
    Print2< COMMON_BASE<int>* >(); // gives: void Print2() [with T = B<int>*]
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sadly, template argument deduction only work in immediate context, and it would be illogical to do otherwise. Think about that example:

```
template<typename T>
using common_base = std::conditional<(sizeof(T) > 8), int, float>

template<typename T>
void call_me(common_base<T>) {
    // ...
}

int main() {
    call_me(1.4f); // What is T?
}
```

It may seem obvious like that, but this is also what's happening with your example. You can imagine this:

```
// Ah! Fooled you compiler!
template<> struct B<int> { using HERE = B<std::string>; };
```

Then after that, what these calls should deduce to?

```
CheckMe(bi); // should deduce B<int> or B<std::string>?
```

As you can see, the compiler cannot deduce through non-immediate context since there may not be a 1:1 relationship, and sometimes it just can't be deducted.

---

What should you do then?

Simplifying the template function is the usual way to make it work:

```
template<typename T>
struct B {
    using HERE = B<T>;
    using type = T;
};

template<typename BaseType>
void CheckMe(BaseType* bt) {
    using VAR_TYPE = BaseType::type; // yay, can use member type
}
```

Comment: But if I have to use overloads to select called functions, I can not first step into it. So I have to generally think about a different design... bad thing but reality :-)

Comment: Overloading works quite well with templates like that too... unless I'm mistaking something? And what do you mean by first step? Like the first "Step in" in the debugger or something?

Comment: My example shows overload and it did not work with getting the type by using from inside of another template. So I can't go ahead with this approach, as I need overloads and a type defined "somewhere".  That in general overloads works with template is quite clear... ;)